# XMPPFramework - Presence not received in iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, user-presence

I am trying to send message from simulator to device. On simulator there is one user while on device there is another user. But presence is not being received at any end.
I am using XMPPFramework for ios.
Here is the code I am using to send presence

```
NSXMLElement *presence = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"presence"];
[presence addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user1@server.com"]];
[presence addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"available"];
[[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
```

But at the end where `user1@server.com` is logged in following method is NOT being invoked

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    NSLog(@"---------- xmppStream:didReceivePresence: ----------");
}
```

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason presence was not being sent is that code was incorrect. I used following code to send presence

```
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
```

after that it showed user online on openfire server and message was correctly being sent to other users.

Comment: Hello. Have you managed to get this XMPP application working?